# Does R have a way of preserving column format when exporting a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, write.table

I often export data.frame's in R but run into the problem when I try to import them back in, lose all of the formatting into date/numeric/logical/factor values and get it all back as character variables instead. It gets kind of old to have to run a cleaning/formatting script over and over again on the same file so I was wondering if there is a way or a parameter on write.table that allows one to conserve all of this?

Comment: Save files as R objects (use `save` or `saveRDS`). Text files or CSV files don't have column classes.

Answer (score 4):

Use `saveRDS` and `readRDS`. These will save and load your data frames into exactly the same format.

Answer (score 3):

If it's tabular data, you can use the new [`feather`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/feather/index.html) format to save your data. That way you can even read it into Python without losing column type information.